# accessing the web user control through jquery on the web form page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-user-controls

I'm building a web user control for ASP.NET. on the main aspx page where I place the user control and I give it an id. the problem is I want to  access it by using Jquery(I have the plugins), but the element of the web user control is "undefined", the jquery works on all the other elements of the web forms page except the web user control that I made.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert($('#userControl').prop('ID')); //returns undefined
    });
```

Comment: I think that part of the problem is that the program enters the web form page first and only later the web user control so the id is undefined because it was not created yet. how do I get passed this?

Comment: alert($("<%=r1.ClientID %>").prop("id")); //returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the right ID to select your control? Try using something like this:

```
var userControllId = "<%=userControll.ClientID %>"
```

That's the correct way to get a user control ID from jQuery

Comment: You are missing a '#' before '<%=r1.ClientID %>'. Try '$("#<%=r1.ClientID %>").prop("id")'